Down arrow is automatically pressing when I click on left arrow key
The left arrow key is moving to the next line or down. When searching on any search engine, it selects the next suggestion by clicking the left arrow key in Windows 10.
However, Ctrl + left arrow works correctly in VSCode, moving the cursor to the previous word, but the left arrow key does not work as usual.
This issue occurs in every application where I can type.
I figured out the down arrow pressed automatically when I press the left, so its taking total two input one is down arrow and one is left arrow
How can I find out why its happening!!

Don't use different (second) account for editing your own question.

Laptop or desktop? If the latter, try another keyboard (borrow from a friend if you don't have another handy). If a laptop, plug in an external keyboard. That will tell you if its hardware or software

Use any external keyboard to test: USB, Bluetooth or other.

As DrMoishe Pippik notes: You need to see if this is a hardware or software issue, and the first step for doing that is to try with a different keyboard. If the problem persists on different keyboards, the problem if with your software and you should proceed with repairing your OS or rolling back any recent changes you made to it. If the problem doesn't happen on a different keyboard, the problem is with your old keyboard and you should simply replace it. This is stage one of troubleshooting issues like this. Please complete it and report back.
